# 403 forbidden when loading traceur

Tags: angular, systemjs

I am getting the following error in my angular2 application

```
Error: XHR error (403 Forbidden) loading http://localhost/myapp/node_modules/traceur
```

I have it in my systemjs.config file

```
(function (global) {
System.config({
    paths: {
        // paths serve as alias
        'npm:': 'node_modules/'
    },

    map: {
        // our app is within the app folder
        app: 'app',
        // angular bundles
        '@angular/core': 'npm:@angular/core/bundles/core.umd.js',
        '@angular/common': 'npm:@angular/common/bundles/common.umd.js',
        '@angular/compiler': 'npm:@angular/compiler/bundles/compiler.umd.js',
        '@angular/platform-browser': 'npm:@angular/platform-browser/bundles/platform-browser.umd.js',
        '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic': 'npm:@angular/platform-browser-dynamic/bundles/platform-browser-dynamic.umd.js',
        '@angular/http': 'npm:@angular/http/bundles/http.umd.js',
        '@angular/router': 'npm:@angular/router/bundles/router.umd.js',
        '@angular/forms': 'npm:@angular/forms/bundles/forms.umd.js',
        // other libraries
        'rxjs': 'npm:rxjs',
        'angular-in-memory-web-api': 'npm:angular-in-memory-web-api',
        'angular-oauth2-oidc': 'npm:angular-oauth2-oidc',
        'traceur':'npm:traceur'
    },

    packages: {
        app: {
            main: './main.js',
            defaultExtension: 'js'
        },
        rxjs: {
            defaultExtension: 'js'
        },
        'angular-in-memory-web-api': {
            main: './index.js',
            defaultExtension: 'js'
        },
        'angular-oauth2-oidc': {
            main: './index.ts',
            defaultExtension: 'ts'
        }
    }
});
```

})(this);

Any thoughts what I am missing?

Comment: The `map` entry for traceur should probably be `'traceur' : 'npm:traceur/bin/traceur.js'`. As it is, it's mapped to traceur directory and it looks like getting directory listing is forbidden in your web server config.